# SelectFeature with Double-Click

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I have the ability to select features on the map with a click using OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature. **How can i add a double-click handler to that?**

I have tried modifying [this code](http://blog.slashpoundbang.com/post/2342888467/openlayers-zoom-when-a-feature-in-a-vector-layer-is) to suite my needs, but it ends up overriding my SelectFeature. So i'm able to handle the double click, but the single click in the SelectFeature stops working.

[DEMO LINK](http://krefft.org/test/ol/doubleclick.html)

DEMO CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map, vectorLayer;

    function init() {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS",
                "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", { layers: 'basic' });

        vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Simple Geometry");

        map.addLayers([layer, vectorLayer]);

        var wkt = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();

        polygonFeature = wkt.read("POLYGON((-85.419086 49.25385,-55.05949 44.951293,-71.090388 1.315632,-91.743655 4.348987,-85.419086 49.25385))");

        vectorLayer.addFeatures([polygonFeature]);
        var bounds = polygonFeature.geometry.getBounds();
        map.zoomToExtent(bounds);

        addClickHandler();
        addDoubleClickHandler();   

    }

    function addDoubleClickHandler() {

        var DblclickFeature = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {
            initialize: function (layer, options) {
                console.log(this);
                OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]);
                this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Feature(this, layer, {
                    dblclick: this.dblclick
                });
            }
        });

        var dblclick = new DblclickFeature(vectorLayer, {
            dblclick: function (event) {
                console.log(event);
            }
        });

        map.addControl(dblclick);
        dblclick.activate();
    }

    function addClickHandler() {

        var handler_featureselected = function (e) {
            console.log("handler_featureselected");
        };
        var handler_featureunselected = function (e) {
            console.log("handler_featureunselected");
        };

        var selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer,
            {
                hover: false,
                clickout: false,
                multiple: true,
                toggle: true,
                //box: true,
                eventListeners: {
                    featurehighlighted: handler_featureselected,
                    featureunhighlighted: handler_featureunselected
                }
                //multipleKey: "shiftKey"
            }
        );

        map.addControl(selectControl);
        selectControl.activate();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: CaptDragon, I'm having exactly the same issue - did you ever figure out a workaround?

Comment: @tairngire I have not, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will get what you're looking for examining [the source code of that page](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/click-handler.html).

Comment: That's part of the code i am using. However, I'm trying to make it work with the SelectFeature. the link to the example you provided does the double click and single click on the map and does not select features. I guess i'll have to come up with my own SelectFeature based on the example you provided. That is, for all the features intersecting the mouse click/dblclick get the topmost and do a feature.select() on it. I'll try it out. But i was hoping to somehow leverage OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature.