# OpenLayers - is it possible for a feature to have both a single click and double click event?

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm have an OpenLayers map with a single vector layer containing many features. I've been using SelectFeature to pop up some info when a feature is clicked, and that's working fine. However, I now want to add some functionality when the feature is double-clicked - specifically I just want to zoom in, and not have the popup appear.

I gave this a shot: http://blog.slashpoundbang.com/post/2342888467/openlayers-zoom-when-a-feature-in-a-vector-layer-is
But it removed my single-click functionality.

Essentially this is the same problem as [SelectFeature with Double-Click](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11832/selectfeature-with-double-click)

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

So I'm trying a workaround using SelectFeature to handle the single click and registering an event listener on the vector layer to handle the double click. All I want to do is zoom in on the double clicked feature. This is what I have:

```
VEClayer.events.register('dblclick', VEClayer, function(e){
    map.zoomToExtent(e.features.geometry.getBounds(), closest=true);
    }
);
```

However now I have another problem, and I'm not sure if it's being caused by having both SelectFeature and the listener active or what. The new issue is that try as I might I can't access any of the event attributes. So when I try to get `e.features.geometry.getBounds()`, Firebug gives me the error `"e.features is undefined"`. I've tried to get this multiple other ways (e.xy, e.longlat, getMousePosition) and it's always the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you look at [OpenLayers.Handler.Click](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/Click-js.html)?

The select control takes an handler as option, and the above one has a boolean that should tell you if is single or double click.

## Example

Not exactly what you asked (select on dblClick; deselect on click) but should be easy to change

```
// Simple WFS layer
wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
    "WFS",
    {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS(
        {
            url:  "/optima/geoserver/wfs",
            featureType: "node",
            featureNS: "http://piemonte.optima.sistemaits.com",
            geometryName: 'poin'
        })
});
map.addLayer(wfs);

// Add a select control (note: this control is added to the map, but is disabled)
var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
    wfs,
    {
        multiple: false,
        clickout: true,             // Will be ignored (aka, you have to deselect a feature when no feature is found onClick)
        onSelect: function(feature)
        {
            // ...
        },
        onUnselect: function(feature)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
);

map.addControl(select);

// Handler to intercept click.
handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
    select,  // The select control
    {
        click: function(evt)
        {
            console.warn(this); // OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature
            var feature = this.layer.getFeatureFromEvent(evt);
            
            // clickout
            if(this.layer.selectedFeatures){
                this.unselect(this.layer.selectedFeatures[0]);
            }
        },
        dblclick: function(evt)
        {
            console.info(this); // OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature
            var feat = this.layer.getFeatureFromEvent(evt);
            // Select a feature
            if(feat){
                this.select(feat);
            }

        }
    },
    {
        single: true,
        double: true,
        stopDouble: true,
        stopSingle: true
    }
);

// select.activate();  // The select control must NOT be active
handler.activate();    // The handler will handles the click events for the select control
```

Comment: Beat me to it. (+1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, though I'm a little stumped as to how to make it work for me. You mean I can pass an instance of a Click handler in the constructor for my SelectFeature like so?

`var clickControl = new OpenLayers.Control.Click();

var selectControls = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(VEClayer,{onSelect: selectFeatureInfo, onUnselect: closeFeatureInfo, handlers: clickControl});`

I'm not really sure how to make them work together; would I move my function calls (selectFeatureInfo, closeFeatureInfo) to my click handler?

Sorry for my lack of knowledge, I'm new to OpenLayers.

Comment: Thank you for that great example!
I always get "undefined" from `var feature = this.layer.getFeatureFromEvent(evt);`
I operate the handler on one Vector layer named "kmlLayer". Even if I try `var feature = kmlLayer.getFeatureFromEvent(evt);` I still get undefined. Any suggestions?

Comment: @mephistho, what's the output of console.log(this)? Did you set  the layer for the control? Or maybe could be that the handler is added to the map and activated *before* the layer is added to the map (the layer should be added before the handler)

Comment: @mephistho, i have same issue. feature get undefined. I have output the console.log(this). log returns me Openlayers.Control.SelectFeature.Openlayers.Class.initialize {}