# openlayers draw feautre(line, polygon) callback

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I need to enable feature drawing functionality. Code:

```
var drawingControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(someLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path);
map.addControl(drawingControl);
```

But I also need to do some actions when drawing is done, on double click.
Therefore, how can I define a `dblclick callback` (for example, add there `console.log("1")`)?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this event if you want to do action immediately after feature is added (no need for double click):
featureadded    Triggered when a feature is added

Something like this:

```
someLayer.events.on({
     "featureadded":
         function(e)
         {
            console.log("1");
         }
    });
```

If you still need double click examine this:

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/click-handler.html

[OpenLayers - is it possible for a feature to have both a single click and double click event?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33149/openlayers-is-it-possible-for-a-feature-to-have-both-a-single-click-and-double)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback function to `OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature` `featureAdded` property, which will be automatically called after you finishing drawing the geometry.

I can image some code like this:

```
var drawingControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(someLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {featureAdded: onFeatureAdded});
map.addControl(drawingControl);

function onFeatureAdded(){
    console.log("1");
}
```